# Does DisplayPort daisy chaining support separate audio outputs for each monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, audio-output

I'm looking at making a setup with several monitors using DisplayPort daisy chaining, using the audio output of the monitors to be able to switch between headphones and speakers in the operating system. So, will I be able to see the two separate monitor outputs as separate audio devices in Windows / Pulseaudio or is daisy chaining only for video?

Further question: would a hub setup be any different or do the same rules apply?

Comment: Were you able to findout @Jakob?

Comment: That's interesting, I'm looking for a similar goal: I would like to have my two monitors play left and right audio as if they were speakers